# How to set available and unavailable times for a google resource for booking?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm looking for a way to set time availability and unavailability of the google calendar resources.

At the moment, I could create google calendar resource with google admin api. But the problem is, I don't know how to set available time for them that could use in booking process — creating an event in google calendar, and assign a resource to that event.

There's no any attribute to address this requirement [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars) in documentation.

Comment: Hi! If I understood your question, you are asking how to create an event with the Calendar API, right? When you create an event, [Freebusy](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy) will return "busy" for that event's period of time. May I ask which language do you want to use?

Comment: @Jescanellas thank you for the response. No, I'm able to create event via calendar API. Actually, I'm going to create calendar resources (rooms) using google admin API. Also it is possible to create calendar resources, but I don't know how to define available time for that room that is used for booking process by an event. Also, I'm using python language. Can you also elaborate what actually is FreeBusy?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. FreeBusy is a query you run against a Calendar to see if a period of time is "busy" or "free" (if there is an event or not), so it might be useful for what you are trying to do. So if you [make a Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/44105?hl=en) for the room, and others create events to "book" time in it, FreeBusy can check if it's available for a certain period of time if you need to book via API. There is no extra attribute for the events, as they are all considered "busy time" by default.

Comment: @Jescanellas As far as I understood about freeBusy query, It returns the busy (unavailable) times on a resource calendar. But the thing I'm looking for is as oppose to it. I want to bound the time range of a resource calendar. I also just sent an answer. please look into that if not bothering you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Apparently, there's no a straight forward procedure for bounding the time range of a resource calendar. So I decided to bound a resource calendar by creating fake events for those time ranges that the calendar should be unavailable. In this way, the users cannot book (i.e. create any events) on those specific time ranges!

OR

You can read every changes on a calendar (polling or push notification if applicable), then compare the created events with your system's events, and if there are any events that have conflicts with the system's events (booking), decline those google calendar events consequently.